# Using R to separate txt file based on fixed width

Tags: r

I am using read_fwf in Package readr to separate columns in txt file.

The code is simple and like:

```
   fwf_widths(c(4,9,3,1,24,17,1
```

However, there is a problem when converting numbers like 01412 -- in the excel (csv) it will become 1412 directly --- (because I have a lot of codes like 001, 0001 then all becomes 1

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In the `read_fwf` you can specify the `col_types`

Comment: yeah, I know, but I have a lot of columns -- how can I speciy one particular column to be 'text' or is it safer to make them all 'text'?

Comment: You can use `col_types = strrep('c', n)` where `n` is the number of columns you expect

Comment: thanks, my understanding this makes all columns become 'character' if n=total number of columns (but if I put 10 -- does it mean the 10th column is character or first 10 become character? thanks!

Comment: Here, I am assuming that you want to read all the columns as character to get the leading 0's.  If you use `strrep('c', 10)#[1] "cccccccccc"`, you have a string with only 'c's  with number of characters 10 signifying each column type i.e. first 10  as character.  If you want it differently `cddddcccc`, some columns are numeric

Comment: I already finish the column position counting --- meaning I already successfully separte by using my script                                                                      
      MasterFile <- read_fwf(file="Master File/UG_APPLICANTS_2017.txt", fwf_widths(c(4,9,3,1,24...........),col_types = strrep('c',676))   just the data type is not right

Comment: Without having a small reproducible example, it is difficult to comment

Comment: The raw data txt file looks like:    2016SVIC NN                                        01407     MOUNT ALEXANDER 7-12 COLLEGE            3031    (not sure if the example of this row helps or not)

Comment: That won't help much.  Where do you get fields like Buenos Aires.  Does it occur in place of 'ALEXANDER`

Comment: Yeah!!!   MOUNT ALEXANDER should be in one column as a location (so I separate by maximum width first) and cannot do it by separate by space  (01407 is the problem I face now -- becoming 1407)

Comment: If you have similar strings, read it with `lines <- readLines('yourfile.csv')` then use `read.table(text = gsub(" ([A-Z]\\w+\\s+?[A-Za-z]+?) ", " '\\1' ", lines), sep=" ", header = FALSE, colClasses = rep("character", 7), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)#
        V1 V2    V3              V4   V5      V6   V7
1 2016SVIC NN 01407 MOUNT ALEXANDER 7-12 COLLEGE 3031`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can read the file with `readLines` and then use `read.table`

```
lines <- readLines('yourfile.csv')
read.table(text = gsub(" ([A-Z]\\w+\\s+?[A-Za-z]+?) ", " '\\1' ", lines),
  sep = " ", header = FALSE,
     colClasses = rep("character", 7), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#        V1 V2    V3              V4   V5      V6   V7
#1 2016SVIC NN 01407 MOUNT ALEXANDER 7-12 COLLEGE 3031
```